# calculating sum of dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down list here :

http://jsfiddle.net/HcPYM/

can't I avoid using the (Distributor) and the (Public) buttons and just show a text automatically appears under the table ?

and if I can't .. can I just add (CHF) beside the number that appears in the message ?

that's the jquery I use

```
eval( $( 'td:nth-child(3)' ).map( function( td, $this ){
    return ( ( parseFloat( ( $this = $( this ) ).text() ) || 0 )
        * ( parseFloat( $this.parent().find( 'select' ).val() ) || 0 ) );
} ).get().join( '+' ) )
```

Please explain in details cuz I'm super beginner

Comment: What's this got to do with PHP?

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate a function without pressing any button?

Comment: I've never seen so much eval before...Anyway, why don't you just update the element you want the total any time that a drop down changes?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `onclick` for the Distributor/Public buttons, you can just update the table (or alert) on the change event of the dropdowns.  The only thing is that how do you know whether they are calculating with "Distributor" or "Public?"

```
$(".pricestable select").on('change', calculate);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HcPYM/2/

I suppose that "Distributor" and "Public" could be radio buttons, and you could make the decision based on that:

```
$(".pricestable select").on('change', function () {
    if ($("#distributor").prop('checked')) {
        calculate();
    }
    else {
        calculate2();
    }
});
```

I also advise against using `eval` -- you can just iterate over the arrays and add them using `+` instead of evaluating the string with `+`es.

Comment: Okay thank you .. but can I write (CHF) beside the number in the message ?

Comment: @DianaTrinca why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: I mean the message that appears .. with the price as button or as update .. I wanna write (CHF) beside that number ? how do I control this message ?

Comment: Explosion .. I've send u a message at explosion-pills@aysites.com please reply me if you got it